# iPhone - UITableView cell label color change

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have UITableView data based on a searched text. How do I highlight the text from UITableViewCell label in all data cells or in whole UITableView?

Such an example if I searched with "Ball", UITableView load with "Red" text contains data need now I need to focus all label contain with "Ball"/"ball" text.

"Ball" is a simple search text.

How? I am using iOS v 8.2 & objective-c

Comment: It seems that the answers below do not match your requirements. People are focussing on making the label change the color, whereas you are asking how to change the color based on a search text. Again, please post your code as in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html)

```
//This needs to go into cellForRowAtIndexPath:
//Set title label
//StrTerm is result, and seachText is text searched for.
//Adjust the fonts according to your needs

NSMutableAttributedString *mattrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[strTerm capitalizedString]];

[mattrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, strTerm.length)];
[mattrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, strTerm.length)];

NSRange range = [[strTerm lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchText lowercaseString]];

[mattrStr setAttributes:@{
                          NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0],
                          NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]
                          } range:range];

cell.textLabel.attributedText = mattrStr;
```

Comment: Its not working in custom UITableViewCell, any idea?

Comment: Are you using your own label on the custom UITableViewCell?

Comment: Not exactly I designed a detail view with some contents ( image, rating, label ...). I want to change that label text color, thats it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to highlight text color of label.
Apply below when u are loading the search content in tableview only..

```
cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

//(OR) if you are using custom cell then use below code...

```
cell.lblRef.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Hope it helps you...!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code..

```
NSString *initial = @"Lorem ipsum and dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, and sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation and ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse and cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.";
        NSString *text = [initial stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"and" withString:@"ex"]; //check for "and" replacing with "or"

        NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];

        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(ex)" options:kNilOptions error:nil];


        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,text.length);

        [regex enumerateMatchesInString:text options:kNilOptions range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

            NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
            [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:subStringRange];
        }];
        [_lableText setAttributedText:mutableAttributedString];
```

[NSMutableAttributedString_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try This.
[TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel)

Hope it helps.